# Unity Dynamically Limiting a Slider in a Custom Editor Panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have attempted this in my panel already by working out the remaining amount of the total percentage and setting that as top limit of slider but that either seems to be inaccurate because my logic is wrong or it breaks the panel.

Currently the panel is scripted as shown below with the maximum the sliders can reach is 10 with a label showing me the total so i dont go over which is highly impractical.

```
public static int ammoxBoxesPercent = EditorPrefs.GetInt("Ammo");
    public static int medicKitsPercent = EditorPrefs.GetInt("MedicKits");
    public static int amountOfItemsPerZone =  EditorPrefs.GetInt("Amount");


    public static int totalPercentageVal;
    public static int maxTotalValue = 10;

    [MenuItem("Enviroment Controls/ Object Spawners Control Panel")]
    private static void showEditor()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow<ObjectSpawnersControlPanel>(false, "OBJ Spawners CP");
    }


    void OnGUI()
    {


            ammoxBoxesPercent = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Ammox Box Percent", ammoxBoxesPercent, 1, 10);
            EditorPrefs.SetInt("Ammo", ammoxBoxesPercent);

            medicKitsPercent = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Medic Kit Percent", medicKitsPercent, 1, 10);
            EditorPrefs.SetInt("MedicKits", medicKitsPercent);


            amountOfItemsPerZone = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Amount of Items Spawned at Each Zone", amountOfItemsPerZone, 1, 5);
            EditorPrefs.SetInt("Amount", amountOfItemsPerZone);

            totalPercentageVal = medicKitsPercent + ammoxBoxesPercent;
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Total Percentage so far : " + totalPercentageVal.ToString() + "0");
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Total must not go above 100");

    }
```

The goal is to have it so when i set the first slider to say 6 i then set the limit of second slider to 4 because the percentage limit is 10 (representing 100 percent in my case)

Anybody know i decent method to achieve this?

Comment: "Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) from Microsoft. Do not use this tag unless you have a specific question about Visual Studio -- not just a coding issue." - Means: You use tags the wrong way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly easy. Just calculate `10 - ammoxBoxesPercent` and use that as the max value for your `IntSlider` for `medicKitsPercent`. 
One thing you'd want to do is to set the lower limit for `medicKitsPercent` to 0, so in case you hit 10 on `ammoxBoxesPercent` (Since you want the total to be 10 at max)

`medicKitsPercent = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Medic Kit Percent", medicKitsPercent, 0, maxTotalValue - ammoxBoxesPercent);`

Comment: Well i had the right idea originally, just the execution was wrong. Thanks for the help it works great.